# Row based database or Column based database

Tags: nosql, bigdata, analytics, rdbms, data-warehouse

We are working on a audit system where auditor are given access to transaction processed in last quarter. Auditor performs various analysis on the data to find out invalid/erroneous transactions that have some exceptions.

Generally, these analysis requires data to be present on some charts to view the out-layers or sometime duplication detection are done based on multiple columns.
Sometime exception detection algorithm are pretty involved that require multiple processing steps using stored procedure.
Please note that analysis rarely involves aggregation on huge rows.

Occasionally , they can change some data if they find it missing or incorrect.
We are evaluating row based (sql & nosql databases) and column store (like data warehouse systems).

Is this a use case for datawarehouse or row based store, like nosql or some RDBMS?

In short, requirements are:
- Occasional update
- Mostly read queries over last 3/months of data
- Reading data my require several messaging steps, like creating temp table in step 1, forming join with another table in step rule, delete some rows ect.

Thanks

Comment: "share his/her thoughts to select" is not an on-topic question. [ask]

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific

Comment: There is nothing in your "requirements" that lets one choose one DBMS or DBMS implementation style over another--and no matter how you edit them there isn't going to be--until you have done enormous research, investigation & estimation--and then you wouldn't need us--and even then you wouldn't know the correct answer for sure without actual multiple implementation & measurement. See my next comment. This sort of question is just too broad. And also not researched--you need to learn & summarize your needs, available DBMSs & your cost/benefit, not ask us to.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Dear philipxy, I had only asked for some directions. Please check the RADO answer. He is spot on while answering this question. We don't live in a ideal world, where you get time for "enormous research & estimation". We would definitely start with something based on some POCs and re-evaluate our decisions after sometime. I understand that this question are not specific, but I believe, it is an important one and can be useful for other as well.

Comment: Hi. That answer just generically says "install & specialize DBMS technology" & gives an example high-level decomposition to products. It is not specific to your question of column vs row DMBS implementation. Also it unjustifiably promotes a certain way to go about that--eg dimensional modeling, Power BI, Tableau. That someone posted that answer does not mean that your question is not too broad or that the answer is good. My comments constitute such a generic answer but the question is too broad so should not be answered. Not all questions are on-topic SO questions. Good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

For your task, it does not really matter how the data is stored. You need to think instead how to create a solid dimensional model, populate it with data properly, and what reporting tools to use.

To give you an example, here are a couple of common setups I've used in my projects:

Microsoft stack setup:

- SQL Server for data storage
- SSIS for data ETL (or write your own stored procedures if you know what you are doing)
- Publish dimensional model on the same SQL Server. If your data set is large (over billion records), use SSAS Tabular instead
- Power Pivot or Power BI for interactive reporting, or SSRS for paginated reports.

Open-source setup:

- PostgreSQL for data storage
- Use stored procedures and/or Python to process data
- Publish dimensional model to another PostgreSQL database. If your data is large, publish the dimensional model to Redshift or
  other columnar database
- Use Tableau or Power BI for interactive reporting, or build your own reporting interface.

I think NoSQL database is a wrong choice here because audit will require highly structured data.

Comment: Hi Rado, Thanks for your answers. Will size be the only criteria to go with warehouse. We are considering GCP BigQuery. I believe, since this is fully managed service, size would not matter. We can go with it even if size is not that huge. What could be other factors that we should consider while selecting database or warehouse in our case. Occasional update could be one. Warehouse are little slow while updating data. We may need some pointed queries, or pagination. These query may be charged at higher rate, as they result into table scan and not index scan, Bigqueryis pay as you go.

Comment: I have no experience with BigQuery, unfortunately. What I would do in a situation like that - create a sample data set and build quick prototypes on whatever platforms you are evaluating. On surface, they all market themselves as great and awesome. But only experience can tell if they really deliver on their promise.

Comment: In my experience, by far the most difficult task is to build a proper, high quality dimensional model from source data. Usually, it's 70-80% of the work, cost and troubles. The rest (reporting, analysis, platform, etc) are much smaller pain. I'd focus your research/evaliations accordingly.

Comment: I understand RADO, thanks for your quick help! By the way, is it ok for fire paginated and pointed query on warehouse. Don't you think these will costlier (in terms of resources consumption) than RDBMS as they will full scan the columns.